# How to stop network callback when app exit?

Tags: android

I'm using networkcallbacks in my app. Everything goes fine but if I exit my app still those callbacks are called.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
//Default methods
});
```

I came up with the solution

```
System.exit(0);
```

Although this solution works but many sites don't recommend to use this code.

So is there any way to unregister or stop these call backs when app exit?

Comment: How do you "exit" from the App? Pressing HOME button is not a real Exit. Neither switch to a different App via "Recent Apps" history....those are just a Suspension.

Comment: @emandt I simply press back button and exit app. The onDestroy method of activity is called still it receive call backs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerDefaultNetworkCallback(android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) for `ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(...)` it does automatically unregister if the app exits. However what you might be referring to is when the app goes into the background?

If so then you can unregister the callback manually in `onPause` with [`ConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#unregisterNetworkCallback(android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) and then re-register in `onResume`.

---

```java
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback callback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback();
connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback);
connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback);
```

Comment: I read that documentation but that unregisterNetworkCallback requires the Networkcallback as a parameter which I'm confused which value to pass?

Comment: You pass in the same callback that you used to register it.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you . I provide the code in my question can you tell me which value to pass?

Comment: So you would need to hold a reference to the callback when you create it (the `new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(...`) and then use that to unregister.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide some more clarity.

Comment: Thank You Henry Twist, Although its not exactly what I'm looking for but your solution helps me in solving the problem.